# Excel VBA execute code in newly created workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to save one worksheet in my excel file to a new file, but without the formula's.

I have this code that is working to get the file saved:

```
Sub SaveInvoice()

 'Create a filename based on invoicenumber
 Dim FileName As String
 FileName = Sheets("Sale").Range("C3").Value

 'Copy the "Print" sheet
 Worksheets("Print").Copy

 With ActiveWorkbook
    'Save the file as new
    .SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName
 End With

End Sub
```

This works like a charm, however I need to strip out the formula's so I googled and fount this piece of code:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
Cells.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

And this works as well, however once I merge the two pieces of code together the whole function breaks.

```
 With ActiveWorkbook
    'Transform cells to values
     ActiveSheet.Copy
     Cells.Copy
     Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the file as new
    .SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName
 End With
```

This results in my base worksheet beeing stripped from formula's.

I need to know how I can call the function on the newle created workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying a worksheet with no `Destination` excel creates a `New Workbook`, and the `New Workbook` with its only `Worksheet` are active.

**EDIT:** I just realized that in the final code these lines from the original code:

```
'Copy the "Print" sheet
 Worksheets("Print").Copy
```

Were moved inside the

```
With ActiveWorkbook
```

That was previously referring to the `New Workbook` created by the `Worksheet.Copy` and that now refers to the `Source Workbook`

So let see what the Op's final code is actually doing:

Here the `ActiveWorkbook` is the [Source Workbook] and the `ActiveSheet` *must be [Print]*

```
With ActiveWorkbook
```

This copies the `ActiveSheet` creating a `New Workbook` with only one sheet

```
     ActiveSheet.Copy
```

These lines are affecting the `ActiveSheet` [Print] in the [Source Workbook].
Not because of the `With` statement but because *it's the one active*

```
    Cells.Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The commands within a `With` intended to affect object that it refers to must start with a dot [.]; however these lines are invalid because Cells and Range are not Methods nor Properties of the Workbook Object, thus en error would have been triggered.

> **With Statement**
>
> Executes a series of statements on a single object or a user-defined type.
>
> *(from the msdn.microsoft.com help)*

This saves the Workbook referred by the `With` statement, *which still has the formulas*

```
   'Save the file as new
   .SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName

End With
```

Try this code:

```
Sub SaveInvoice_TEST_1()
'Create a filename based on invoicenumber
Dim FileName As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        FileName = .Sheets("Sale").Range("C3").Value
        'Copy the "Print" sheet
        .Worksheets("Print").Copy
    End With
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Rem Replace Formulas with Values
        .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value2
        'Save the file as new
        .SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName
    End With
    End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

Comment: Strange it worked well in all my tests, nevertheless just make an edit try now and let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following. Read the help page for 'ActiveSheet.Copy' - note that it creates a new workbook and activates it

```
Dim MyWkbk as workbook 

set MyWkbk = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveSheet.Copy

With ActiveWorkbook
    Cells.Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

   'Save the file as new
   .SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName
   '.close
End With


MyWkBk.activate
```

Comment: Well, That's the strange thing. ActiveSheet.Copy does create a copy but it doesn't seem to activate the copied file. Except for saving, that is the only function I can run in the "With ActiveWorkbook"

Comment: `Sheet.Copy` is behaving as as expected, the problem lies in the incorrect use of the `With` statement. see [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EEM the solution was found.

Here's the code I used:

```
Sub SaveInvoice()
    Dim FileName As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Create a filename based on invoicenumber
        FileName = .Sheets("Sale").Range("C3").Value

        'Copy the "Print" sheet
        .Worksheets("Print").Copy
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        'Replace Formulas with Values
        .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value2

        'Save the file as new
        .SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName
    End With
End Sub
```